# How do I make a subclass immutable in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to make my `TextElement` class immutable.

```java
// in AbstractElement.java
public abstract class AbstractElement {

    private String elementName;

    public AbstractElement(String elementName) {
        this.elementName = elementName;
    }

    public String getElementName() {
        return elementName;
    }
}

// in TextElement.java
public final class TextElement extends AbstractElement {

    private String value;

    public TextElement(String elementName, String value) {
        super(elementName);
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public TextElement withValue(String newValue) {
        return new TextElement(elementName, newValue);
    }

    // Is this the best way to create a "setter" for fields in the abstract class?
    public TextElement withElementName(String newElementName) {
        return new TextElement(newElementName, value);
    }
}
```

Is the method `withElementName` in `TextElement` the best way to make `TextElement` immutable while allowing `elementName` to be changed?

Comment: It looks fine for me. Your class is already immutable. Also, I would make `value` attribute `final`.

Comment: If you want to make `elementName` mutable then the abstract class *has to* add a setter for said field. But generally it is quite messy and obscure when you're mixing mutable and immutable classes / fields. -> "*When I change this field will I get a new instance, because it's immutable, or do I modify this instance?*"

Comment: The base class is already immutable so you did not really change anything about it. And if the base class were mutable you would be out of luck since removing the mutability would either be impossible (e.g. for a `final` setter) or you would make Liskov pretty sad.

Comment: @Héctor yep i forgot to add `final` when transfering the code. Is there any alternative like adding the withElementName method into the abstract class (somehow), so that when the abstract class has a new field all subclasses will inherit that method?

Comment: @r0wletc0der that's not possible because you can't instantiate the subclass from the abstract class in a generic way. The only thing you can do is to declare withElementName method as abstract in the abstract class, so all subclasses must implement it.